# tkinter Treeview. Fix total width or disable heading to be dragged out of screen

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have a `ttk.TreeView` widget, which works perfectly. To wrap it in my GUI's window, I use .grid method.
I call `ttk.Treeview().column` and `ttk.Treeview().heading` methods to adjust the text of my headings and the initial/minimal width of the columns.
This is how the header looks:
[initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bVpS.png)

Not bad, but I will need to adjust the widths of some columns during the work, so I can drag it by mouse, manually. The columns will never pass the left border of the frame, but the right border has no limit for columns, so I can drag one or several columns out of the screen. See the picture:
[out of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2bcB.png)

Eventually I can shrink all columns to the left border, with white space at the right of them:
[shrink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ4d6.png)

So I would like to fix the very right separator and to keep other separators to be moved freely. Just to let it be fixed at the right border same way as at the left one.
Is it possible?